# Where does each type of neural network (RNN, CNN, LSTM, etc.) excel?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

For instance, I know CNN excel at analyzing images.

Where do other types excel?

Answer (score 1):

Not a very thorough answer, but you have to understand two things first:

**FNN and RNN are network types**

FNN is a feed forward neural network and RNN is a [recurrent neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network). These aren't architectures themselves.

**> Recurrent Neural Networks**

Recurrent neural networks are generally good for data where there is a relation between previous inputs and the current input.

- LSTM - great for detecting/predicting patterns that occur over long time spans
- GRU - same as LSTM
- Hopfield - great for *remembering* trained patterns, not for *detecting* them
- NARX - great for detecting/predicting patterns over a fixed time span

**> Feed Forward Neural Networks**

Feed forward neural networks cannot detect relationships between previous inputs and the current input.

- CNN -  Great for data with dimensionality, also great for data where the 'location' of neurons matter
- MLP - A regular fully connected network, can basically map any function

**Last note**

Most of these 'architectures' get combined often: for example, if you want to detect emotion in a video, you will most likely need to use a combination between CNN and LSTM.